# sas9.4 interactive data analysis discontinued

Tags: sas

I have SAS 9.4 installed. When I tried to do Solution -> Analysis -> Interactive Data Analysis, it says "ERROR: SAS/INSIGHT has been discontinued, beginning with SAS 9.4."

Do I used version 9.3 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [SAS Community](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Replacement-for-SAS-Insight-and-SAS-Lab/td-p/28177) message board post "Replacement for SAS/Insight (and SAS/Lab)"

> IML Studio is the intended substitute for Insight, although it is a separate product and requires a license for IML.

You might also want to contact your SAS support and ask them if there is a newer current best alternative.  A vote (or request) to bring it back can be lodged at Communities [SASware Ballot](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SASware-Ballot-Ideas/idb-p/sas_ideas) message board.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the stuff that SAS/Insights could do you can now do with the various tasks that come with the SAS/Studio interface.  With SAS 9.4 you should have access to SAS/Studio.  If you are using SAS on your PC it should already be there.  If you are using SAS on shared server(s) then your system team will need to install it and tell what URL to use to launch it.